# How to cause the texture through the glass?

Tags: light, glass, roughness

I would like to engrave some letter behind the glass, and then just put the light behind the glass to project the letter throughout the glass as a magnifier . I tried it by transparent shader ,but seems like only got the pure light can through the glass, and all the roughness and color can’t through the glass. Please help me to do that.
[image]

Comment: Could you post an image of your material setup, and maybe also a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add reference image of what you want to get.

Comment: are you using Cycles or Eevee? Maybe share your file so that we can test? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? The text is engraved into back side of a scaled cube. Make sure to change the blend mode (highlighted on the right):

[image: Glass]

Comment: yes i did, but still cant see the text shadows on the wall. :(